# ASP.Net don't match the Access Date/Time Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to sort for today. I am giving match error while I am comparing.

```
OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Dragonfly\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\App_Data\\calismagunluk.mdb");
OleDbDataReader oku;
OleDbCommand sorgu =new OleDbCommand();
DateTime bugun = DateTime.Now.Date;
sorgu.CommandText = "select * from calisan where kulID=" + sesionKulId + 
    " AND gun='" + bugun + "' ";
 oku = sorgu.ExecuteReader();//I give error in here
    if (oku.HasRows) { 
    Repeater1.DataSource = oku;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    oku.Dispose();}
    else{
        Repeater1.Visible = false;
        repeaterBos.Text = "Bugün Hiç Çalışma Yapmamışsınız...";
        oku.Dispose();
    }
```

I am getting this error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

If I change the db column to Text, it is working. But I don't want it this way. How should I follow the way?

Comment: you should change begun to a format you database has for datetime

Comment: There is a format mismatch between `DateTime.ToString()` and the type expected by your db. What's the type of the column in the db ?

Comment: What is the type of your `kulID` and `gun` columns?

Comment: @Bun Column name gun and column type Date/Time

Comment: @SonerGönül kulID Column type Auto Increment, gun type Date/Time

Comment: What is the type of `sorgu` ? is it `OleDbCommand` or `SqlCommand` also what database you are using ? and **why can't you use parameters instead of string concatenation**

Comment: @Bun my db .mdb extension and Microsof Access

Comment: @Habib I say the header Access . OleDbCommand

Comment: @OnePage, the best place to add technology names is tags, sometimes people can miss it reading in the headers :). I have edited out your post and added the tag ms-access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass the format problem and let the command work the format by itself by using parameters:

```
OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Dragonfly\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\App_Data\\calismagunluk.mdb");
OleDbDataReader oku;
OleDbCommand sorgu =new OleDbCommand();
DateTime bugun = DateTime.Now.Date;
sorgu.CommandText = "select * from calisan where kulID=@ID AND gun=@date";
sorgu.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = susionKulId;
sorgu.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = bugun;
```

Comment: I useing this way and I give error:'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType' does not contain a definition for 'TypeOfID'

Comment: @OnePage I meant for you to change that part for the type of your ID data. In your case I think you mentioned that column being an int, so use `OleDbType.Integer`.

Comment: But giving error "OleDbType.DateTime" this parameters. not only TypeOfID parameters

Comment: @OnePage Oops, I tried to do it by memory but failed :) It's actually `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have the another problem. 30.12.1899 14:10:00-30.12.1899 15:20:00

Comment: From what I saw on your other comment, you want only the Time or you just want to remove the seconds from the complete DateTime ?

Comment: I said the other comment: "I use the Repeater". Repeater have 3 column and Work Time Range, Project Name and Actions. Work Time Range, he start work and finish work range 14:10-15:20. Project Name, your did project name and Actions, edit and erase. Work Time Range is result 30.12.1899 14:10:00-30.12.1899 15:20:00. I want only 14:10-15:20. Total Work Time is label and I have it made the removal and addition operation

Comment: @OnePage At this point I think you should open a new question so your question may reach more people who are better suited than me to answer.